# Getting dataset for building association rules with Weka

Tags: dataset, associations, weka

Where can I find data to construct association rules with Weka? The data could be on any topic.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the example dataset used in the following class, [Association Rule Mining with WEKA](http://maya.cs.depaul.edu/classes/ect584/weka/associate.html), you might want to try the [market-basket dataset](http://inf.abdn.ac.uk/~hnguyen/teaching/CS5553/prac05.php).

Also, please note that several datasets are listed on Weka website, in the [Datasets](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index_datasets.html) section, some of them coming from the [UCI repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) (e.g., the [Plants Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Plants)).

Answer (score 0):

The datasets that are usually used in the association rule mining litterature can be found here:

fimi.ua.ac.be/data/

However, they probably are not in the Weka format. So to use them, you would maybe need to convert them.